# After running dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text); line it goes to catch block. How to solve it?

Tags: java

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] text, PublicKey key) throws InvalidKeyException,
    BadPaddingException,
    IllegalBlockSizeException,
    NoSuchPaddingException,
    NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        byte[] dectyptedText = null;

        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        String transformation = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);

        // decrypt the text using the private key
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);



        return new String(dectyptedText);
    }
```

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
>       at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:358)
>       at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
>       at com.nevaeh.blroimport.util.RSAEncription.decrypt(RSAEncription.java:142)
>       at com.nevaeh.blroimport.util.RSAEncription.decrypt(RSAEncription.java:111)
>       at com.nevaeh.blroimport.ui.MainUI.getCodeFromKeyFile(MainUI.java:391)
>       at com.nevaeh.blroimport.ui.MainUI.prepareCopySummary(MainUI.java:493)
>       at com.nevaeh.blroimport.ui.MainUI.access$1500(MainUI.java:37)
>       at com.nevaeh.blroimport.ui.MainUI$5.run(MainUI.java:684)

Comment: What do you think `BadPaddingException` means?  Did you search the web? What did you find? Did the other StackOverflow hits not answer your question?  Without details on how you created the ciphertext (i.e. the code) and whether it was encoded (i.e. Base64) in transit and the code that did that as well, it will be very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Also notice that you are trying to decrypt with the public key decrypt(byte[] text, PublicKey key). But in the comments says // decrypt the text using the private key.